# When is destructor called for C# classes in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, destructor

Say, I have my own C# class defined as such:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        //Do the work
    }
    ~MyClass()
    {
        //Destructor
    }
}
```

And then I create an instance of my class from an ASP.NET project, as such:

```
if(true)
{
    MyClass c = new MyClass();
    //Do some work with 'c'

    //Shouldn't destructor for 'c' be called here?
}

//Continue on
```

I'd expect the destructor to be called at the end of the `if` scope but it never is called. What am I missing?

Comment: It will be called when the garbage collector is working, and you can't know when this will happen.

Comment: So, what is the purpose of destructors in C# then?

Comment: same as other language's destructor does, free up memory & resources.

Comment: @c00000fd Releasing system resources correctly. You can't assume the GC to know how those are to be released.

Comment: Well, I guess I spent too long with C/C++. In my view destructors are called at the end of the scope where the variable they represent is declared in.

Comment: If your class uses unmanaged resources you can use the destructor to release those properly. If it doesn't use managed resources a destructor is rarely ever necessary...
Additionally, C# works a little different than usual C++ -> you lose the reference to an object, when the reference goes out of scope when you `new`ed an object. Eventually the GC will destroy the object on the heap. Automatic variables are destroyed when they go out of scope.

Comment: @c00000fd In C/C++ you still need to call `delete` on objects that were created with `new`. In C#, the GC does that for you.

Comment: @Nolonar: Yes, indeed. In a very old fashioned C. Nowadays I'd use the RAII concept: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The equivalent to a C++ destructor is `IDisposable` and the `Dispose()` method, often used in a `using` block.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx

What you are calling a destructor is better known as a `Finalizer`.

Here's how you would use IDisposable. Note that `Dispose()` is not automatically called; the best you can do is to use `using` which *will* cause `Dispose()` to be called, even if there is an exception within the `using` block before it reaches the end.

```
public class MyClass: IDisposable
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        //Do the work
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Clean stuff up.
    }
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
using (MyClass c = new MyClass())
{
    // Do some work with 'C'
    // Even if there is an exception, c.Dispose() will be called before
    // the 'using' block is exited.
}
```

You can call `.Dispose()` explicitly yourself if you need to. The only point of `using` is to automate calling `.Dispose()` when execution leaves the `using` block for any reason.

See here for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Basically, the `using` block above is equivalent to:

```
MyClass c = new MyClass();

try
{
    // Do some work with 'C'
}

finally
{
    if (c != null)
        ((IDisposable)c).Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see. I need to have `using` block, right? Because `Dispose` method is not called without it.

Comment: @c00000fd That's correct, although you could call `c.Dispose()` explicitly yourself if you need to. The purpose of `using` is to handle automatically calling it. I'll add some more info to the answer in a sec.

Comment: why does the finally block have  ((IDisposable)c).Dispose(); instead of just  c.Dispose(); . Aren't they both the same thing?

Comment: @user20358 It's for when the `Dispose()` method has been implemented using `explicit interface implementation`. In such cases, you have to cast to call it.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way you can *control* a timing or make a guess on when actually destructor of the object will be called. It's all up to the `Garbage Collector`.

The only think you can be sure, in this case, that at the moment you leave that scope the object `c` becomes unreachable (I assume there are no global references to that instance inside the scope), so the instance `c` is *intended* to be identified and removed by `Garbage Collector` when time comes.

Comment: OK. Thank you. It explains it. Although it makes destructors almost completely useless in C#.

Comment: @c00000fd: will you may think about it like a special event (kind of it) that raised by CLR when your instance is collected, so it *may* have some use, but surely not in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

It is up to the garbage collector as to when an object is freed up. However you can force an object to be freed up by calling [Finalize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). or [GC.Collect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357.aspx) which will force the garbage collector to take action.

Comment: Well, the whole point of using destructors (in a language I'm familiar with -- C/C++) is to have them called implicitly. If I have to call them explicitly, then I can just be OK with a simple method. So I guess the whole concept of RAII is out of the window in C# too, hah?

Comment: @c00000fd - C# is a managed language - let the CLR take care of memory allocation for you, it will finalize the object when it deems appropriate.  However you can force it via `GC.Collect` like I mention in my answer.

Comment: That still doesn't force the garbage collector. Just puts it on a higher priority thread.

Comment: @nunespascal - according to MSDN it Forces an immediate garbage collection of all generations.

Comment: The reason I need the destructor to be called on that spot is because I need the object (named mutex) to be released on that particular spot. I can't wait for the garbage collector to come in...

Comment: @c00000fd The equivalent to a C++ destructor is `IDisposable` and the `Dispose()` method, often used in a `using` block. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx What you are calling a destructor is better known as a `Finalizer`, and it's quite different from a C++ destructor.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Hmm. Very nice. So how would I add it to my class. Simply deriving it from `IDisposable` and providing `public void Dispose(){}` doesn't seem to work. The `Dispose()` is not called at the end of the if() scope.